# How do I show that $w = \frac{1}{(z-a)^n}$ is an analytic function using the Cauchy Riemann equations,where z = x + iy?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, analyticity, cauchy-riemann-equations

I know I need to use the Cauchy Riemann equations, to test for the analyticity, but  how do I break the function  $w = \frac{1}{(z-a)^n}$  into real and imaginary parts?

Comment: I prefer not to use the Cauchy-Riemann equations to prove analyticity of complex functions.

Comment: What is $n$? Where do you want analyticity? Is is necessary to use C-R equations? It is much simpler to use the fact that ratio of two analytic functions is analytic in a region where the denominator does not vanish.

Comment: Yes, it is necessary to use the C-R equations.

Comment: @TuzzSamuel If you want people to use the C-R equations to show analyticity, I suggest editing the question to specify this.

Comment: I tried writing up an answer for this, but gave up because it came out too messy to be reading once written up. But, you might fare better than me. First write $\frac{1}{((x + iy) - (a + ib))^n}$ as $\frac{(x - a + i(y - b))^n}{((x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2)^n}$ by realising the denominator. Then apply binomial theorem on the numerator. You may want to split into $n$ is odd/even cases. Separate out real and imaginary parts, then use quotient rule to differentiate, and various binomial coefficient laws to simplify. It's seriously messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

$z = x + iy, \tag 1$

$a = \sigma + i\omega, \tag 2$

$z - a = (x - \sigma) + i(y - \omega); \tag 3$

$\dfrac{1}{z - a} = \dfrac{1}{(x - \sigma) + i(y - \omega)} = \dfrac{(x - \sigma) - i(y - \omega)}{(x - \sigma)^2 + (y - \omega)^2}$
$= \dfrac{x - \sigma}{(x - \sigma)^2 + (y - \omega)^2} - i\dfrac{y - \omega}{(x - \sigma)^2 + (y - \omega)^2} = u(x, y) + iv(x, y); \tag 4$

it follows that

$u(x, y) = \dfrac{x - \sigma}{(x - \sigma)^2 + (y - \omega)^2} \tag 5$

and

$v(x, y) = - \dfrac{y - \omega}{(x - \sigma)^2 + (y - \omega)^2} \tag 6$

are the real and imaginary parts of $(z - a)^{-1}$, respectively.  At this point it is a relatively easy matter to apply the Cauchy-Riemann equations to $u(x, y)$ and $v(x, y)$ directly, though the necessary algebra is a bit tedious:

writing

$u(x, y) = (x - \sigma)((x - \sigma)^2 + (y - \omega)^2)^{-1}, \tag 7$

$v(x, y) = - (y - \omega)((x - \sigma)^2 + (y - \omega)^2)^{-1}, \tag 8$

we have

$u_x(x, y) = ((x - \sigma)^2 + (y - \omega)^2)^{-1} -2(x - \sigma)^2((x - \sigma)^2 + (y - \omega)^2)^{-2}$
$ = \dfrac{1}{(x - \sigma)^2 + (y - \omega)^2} - \dfrac{2(x - \sigma)^2}{((x - \sigma)^2 + (y - \omega)^2)^2}$
$= \dfrac{(x - \sigma)^2 + (y - \omega)^2}{((x - \sigma)^2 + (y - \omega)^2)^2} - \dfrac{2(x - \sigma)^2}{((x - \sigma)^2 + (y - \omega)^2)^2}$
$= \dfrac{(y - \omega)^2 - (x - \sigma)^2}{((x - \sigma)^2 + (y - \omega)^2)^2}; \tag 9$

we also have

$v_y(x, y) = -((x - \sigma)^2 + (y - \omega)^2)^{-1} + 2(y - \omega)^2((x - \sigma)^2 + (y - \omega)^2)^{-2}$
$ = -\dfrac{1}{(x - \sigma)^2 + (y - \omega)^2} + \dfrac{2(y - \omega)^2}{((x - \sigma)^2 + (y - \omega)^2)^2}$
$= -\dfrac{(x - \sigma)^2 + (y - \omega)^2}{((x - \sigma)^2 + (y - \omega)^2)^2} + \dfrac{2(y - \omega)^2}{((x - \sigma)^2 + (y - \omega)^2)^2}$
$= \dfrac{(y - \omega)^2 - (x - \sigma)^2}{((x - \sigma)^2 + (y - \omega)^2)^2}; \tag{10}$

comparing (9) and (10) we see that

$u_x(x, y) = v_y(x, y); \tag{11}$

a similar calculatinon validates

$u_y(x, y) = -v_x(x, y), \tag{12}$

and thus, with of course the proviso that $z \ne a$,

$\dfrac{1}{z - a} = u(x, y) + iv(x, y) \tag{13}$

satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations, and hence is holomorphic.

The preceding calculations may be simplified somewhat if we express $(z - a)^{-1}$ in term of a polar coordinate system centered at $a$; that is, we write

$z = a + re^{i\theta}, \tag{14}$

whence

$\dfrac{1}{z - a} = (z - a)^{-1}$
$= (re^{i\theta})^{-1} = r^{-1}e^{-i\theta} = \dfrac{\cos \theta}{r} - i\dfrac{\sin \theta}{r} = u(r, \theta) + iv(r, \theta); \tag{15}$

the [Cauchy-Riemann equations in such a polar coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations) are given by

$u_r = \dfrac{1}{r}v_\theta, \tag{16}$

$v_r = -\dfrac{1}{r}u_\theta; \tag{17}$

now a relatively simple calculation shows that, with $u(r, \theta)$ and $v(r, \theta)$ as in (15),

$\left ( \dfrac{\cos \theta}{r} \right)_r = -\dfrac{\cos \theta}{r^2} = \dfrac{1}{r} \left ( -\dfrac{\sin \theta}{r} \right)_\theta;$
$\left ( -\dfrac{\sin \theta}{r} \right)_r = \dfrac{\sin \theta}{r^2} = -\dfrac{1}{r} \left ( \dfrac{\cos \theta}{r} \right)_\theta,  \tag{18}$

again establishing that $(z - a)^{-1}$ is holomorphic away from $z = a$, though with much less effort.

Once we have that $(z - 1)^{-1}$ is a holomorphic function, we may simply invoke the well-known fact that the product of holomorphic functions is again holomorphic to affirm that

$\dfrac{1}{(z - a)^2} = \dfrac{1}{z - a} \dfrac{1}{z - a} \tag{19}$

is holomorphic, and then use a simple inductive argument, assuming that $(z - a)^{-k}$ is holomorphic for $k \in \Bbb N$, to see that

$\dfrac{1}{(z - a)^{k + 1}} = \dfrac{1}{(z - a)^k}\dfrac{1}{z - a} \tag{20}$

is also holomrphic; we conclude that $(z - a)^{-n}$ is holomorphic for all $n \in \Bbb N$.  $OE\Delta$.

Answer (score 0):

For $z_0≠a$ you have a quotient of analytic functions with non-vanishing denominator in a neighborhood of $z_0$. Hence it is analytic at $z_0$.(It is not hard to prove this for a general quotient $f/g$ by definition of the derivative)